# How to show notification after doing a background process in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app using Flutter that uses a database. I am struggling to make the app run a background process to access the database and show that as a notification.

I have used `flutter_local_notifications` & `background_fetch` but I am struggling so much at implementing the functionality that I am seeking.

Can anyone guide me on how I can accomplish that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you worked on? We need to see your efforts first to improve upon. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on Android by using `AlarmManager` package instead of `background_fetch`.

I set the AlarmManager to repeat, and every time it is fired it calls a function that reads from the database and fires a notification.